# Use single deployment group for multiple projects azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have one azure devops organization with 1 project, using the organizations deployment pool.
I've recently created a second project (newProject2) and want to use these same agents in the organizations pool.
Without configuring anything, the pools already show up in newProject2. See below:
[image: pools]

However, when I want to reference them in my `.yml` pipeline, like so:
[image: yaml pool ref]

I get the following message while trying to execute the pipeline: `Enviroment required`.
However, all the agents installed on the machines are registered in the other project's environment and I have to install a new agent on the same machine to have them show up in newProject2. This is understandably not recommended and a dead end.
As I understand it, the usage of a deployment group is only available in a [classic pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops). This has several drawbacks which I won't go into here.

My question is: Is it possible to deploy to an existing deployment pool from multiple (a different/secondary) projects (in a .yml pipeline) and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to deploy to an existing deployment pool from multiple (a different/secondary) projects (in a .yml pipeline) and if so, how?

I am afraid that there is no such method could achieve your requirements for the time being.

There are two limits:

1.In YAML Pipeline, we could only use the Pipeline Environments. The deployment group couldn't be using in YAML pipeline.

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc: [Deployment group jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

2.When you share the pipeline env between projects, it is shared in the form of a deployment group.

Therefore, the same pipeline environment cannot be reused in YAML pipelines of different projects.

But your requirement makes sense.

Here are the suggestion tickets in our UserVoice site:

[Use Deployment groups in a multi-stage yaml file.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/use-deployment-groups-in-a-multi-stage-yaml-file/665340)

[Shared Pipeline Environments within Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/shared-pipeline-environments-within-projects/889113)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin and the links. This feature seems past "nice-to-have" to me. I'll vote accordingly on the M$ boards.